# Changing the country on iPhone for localization testing

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I can change the language in Settings->General->International but how can I change the **country** on a physical iPhone so that I can test my localization is working correctly?

Comment: Regarding the vote to close as off-topic: As a programmer I need to know this in order to test the localization of my app. More specifically, I need to know exactly what configuration settings will affect the locale (as accessed from code) and also affect the localized nib file loading. In that respect I don't think it's any different from a question about an IDE, compiler tool, or test-framework. Testing on real devices is an important part of development.

Comment: Are you talking about the location of the device? How / from where do you fetch the country?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist No, this question is about the locale settings. The answer from rmaddy below is the correct answer, but iPhone doesn't load country-specific nib files so this setting only affects the locale. I have to apply country-specific differences in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with the Settings->General->International->Region Format setting.

It is the region format that determines the locale.

Comment: I've tested this and it seems to change the locale, but not which view controller nib files get loaded. I have `en.lproj` `es.lproj` and `es-PE.lproj` directories with localized xib files, but when I set the language to Spanish and the region format to Perú it just loads the Spanish xib. I think this answer probably is correct, but I have a different problem - need to investigate some more.

Comment: Turns out the iPhone doesn't load region-specific localizations, it only looks for the language-specific files. So Marking as correct since the NSLocale is correctly set by this setting. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-SW1

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a networked application, you could use a proxy server in another country. You'd have to use Wifi while doing so though.